# R - How do I plot a histogram with a specific y-axis (rather than just frequency)?

Tags: r, plot, histogram, standard-deviation

I'm looking to create a histogram which plots a ranking (1-400ish values) along the x-axis and a frequency per 1000 people on the y-axis. Is there a way to do this with the hist() function? Currently I am using plot.default() like so:

```
plot.default(frequencyData$Deprivation.rank, frequencyData$Prescription.per.1000.people, xlab = 
"Deprivation Rank", ylab = "per 1000", main=graph_title, xlim=NULL, ylim=NULL, type="h")
```

Once I have this done I would like to calculate the mean and standard deviation and plot them as a line on the graph I am getting [which currently (using plot.deafult) looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddaP5.png)

Anyone able to provide any help?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any data to test with, but I suppose you can do it without any particular problem. Just use the `hist()` function.

Here's the documentation which you can reach typing `?hist` in the R console:

> ## Histograms Description
>
> The generic function hist computes a histogram
>   of the given data values. If `plot = TRUE`, the resulting object of
>   class "histogram" is plotted by `plot.histogram`, before it is returned.
>
> ```
> Usage hist(x, ...)
> ```
>
> ### Default S3 method:
>
> ```
> hist(x, breaks = "Sturges",
>    freq = NULL, probability = !freq,
>    include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE,
>    density = NULL, angle = 45, col = NULL, border = NULL,
>    main = paste("Histogram of" , xname),
>    xlim = range(breaks), ylim = NULL,
>    xlab = xname, ylab,
>    axes = TRUE, plot = TRUE, labels = FALSE,
>    nclass = NULL, warn.unused = TRUE, ...)
> ```

So, you can try changing the plot function as this:

```
hist(
  frequencyData$Deprivation.rank,
  frequencyData$Prescription.per.1000.people,
  xlab = "Deprivation Rank",
  ylab = "per 1000",
  main = graph_title,
  xlim = NULL,
  ylim = NULL
)
```

#### ggplot alternative

You can obtain a better-looking graph by using the `ggplot` library, like this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(frequencyData, aes(Deprivation.rank, Prescription.per.1000.people)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  xlab("Deprivation Rank") +
  ylab("per 1000") +
  ggtitle(graph_title)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So when I plot this the y-axis does not look the same as the graph above. [Instead it appears like this](https://imgur.com/vqeyGIM.jpg), which as far as I can tell is just the frequencies that each deprivation rank occurs in the data?

Comment: Without any data it's hard to tell. Try removing the `type = "h"` option or even better, try to use the `ggplot` alternative, like in the edited answer.